# AWS CLI command: Timestamp format to view the EC2 instances created on a given date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

We are about the automate the deletion of EC2 instances using AWS CLI. Planning to filter the instances created on a given date.

Came across the below CLI commands to view and terminate the instances

`describe-instances` - to get the list of instances created on the given date range

`terminate-instances` - to terminate the instances returned from "describe-instance" command

Just wanted to know, What is format of time-stamp value, to be given in the "Launchtime" filter value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

per the doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstances.html

> `launch-time` The time when the instance was launched (**for example,
>   2010-08-07T11:54:42.000Z**).
>
> Type: DateTime

so the following should work

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters launch-time=2010-08-07T11:54:42.000Z
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Also want to thank you for providing the API reference URL, which sheds light to refer another way of AWS docs reference.